# How to connect a 50 amp, 4-wire receptacle on my home fuse box for emergency power into my 30 amp 3-wire supply portable generator?

Tags: electrical

No further info to provide for this question. Have not tried to mate the 3-prong and 4-prong together, yet.

Comment: Model # of generator? Is the "4-wire receptacle" an inlet ("prongs", i.e., designed for a generator or other backup power) or an outlet ("holes", like you would plug an appliance into it)? Is the 30A supply from the generator 120V or 240V?

Comment: And the most important question of all: **Do you have an interlock to prevent backfeeding of the utility supply?**

Comment: It is a 120V generator. I would isolate the house from the utility supply manually by throwing the main breaker. The 50 amp 4-wire receptacle is for 4 prong generator back up power.

Comment: You **must** (NEC, utility regulations, etc.) use an actual physical interlock. Hopefully the generator inlet circuit is positioned properly for that. **Upload a picture of the panel** and we can figure it out.

Comment: You need to use a generator interlock.  Also you need to use an inlet not what is referred to "suicide cord".

Comment: Can you post photos of your electrical panel, as well as the make and model of your generator please?

Answer (score 7):

### You need to use a *generator interlock*.

The most important part of a generator installation is an interlock which guarantees that the panel can't be fed from both utility and generator at the same time.

We can't give any more advice about interlock selection, because you didn't give us any more information about your setup.  They are often seen as "transfer switches" in one style or another.

**Do not backfeed a panel without the use of an interlock.**

### And you need to use an *inlet* not a suicide cord.

I'm impressed that you call it a "receptacle" and not a "socket" or "outlet" like everyone else does.  Now, a suicide cord is a cord that has prongs on both ends.  It is not safe for a variety of reasons, but even when used as designed, it's easy to trip over it, pull it out of the socket, and now a loose cord is whipping around that has sparky bits on the end.

The core concept in *receptacle* design is that the pointy bits (male) are *never* the supply and *always* the load.  The inny bits (female) are always the supply, and are inherently guarded against accidental contact.

So, to hook a generator to a house, you use a special type of receptacle called an **inlet**.  It's wall-mounted like an outlet, but inside it are prongy bits.   You use this with a normal/conventional extension cord - i.e. one end is male and the other is female.

But when the house is on utility power, why isn't the prongy bits of the "inlet" energized and dangerous?  Well, the aforementioned *generator interlock* takes care of that.

Comment: I don’t want to go thru the expense of installing an interlock. I feel comfortable using common sense to avoid back feeding the utility power by throwing the main breaker to isolate the house. Then connect the suicide cord, start the generator, and stop the generator before disconnecting the cord. That way the exposed prongs are never energized. I just want to know which wire of the four on the 50 amp pigtail will not be used on the 30 amp plug.

Comment: Harp, excellent answer as usual. A generator interlock is also called a manual transfer switch with hardware  that prevents the generator breaker and main breaker for being connected at the same time, as you said.  The only thing I want to add if the panel is older and is a "split bus panel" it's practically impossible to properly install a gen interlock.  If so, then they are reduced to those silly and very expensive Generac MTS with a power inlet.

Comment: @Bruce  a simple generator interlock is less than $100.   What happens if the power goes out and some other household member wants to start the generator when you're not there???  Be safe, do it right, not only that, if and when you go to sell your home, it will pass IF you don't do it wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way @Bruce.  Real world experience has shown that people who think they're smart, and can do it on a sunny day when not in a rush, tend to make stupid mistakes in the cold dark. Or simply they are not there and someone else is trying to sort it.  **"In a crisis people don't rise to the occasion. They sink to the level of their training." - Marine Corps** ... and that's why interlocks and "not suicide cords" are required.

Comment: Do you feel comfortable pleading guilty to murder by electrocution of a utility worker?

Answer (score 2):

#### Step 1 - Interlock

See Harper's answer. Hopefully the existing generator inlet circuit is in the right place for an interlock. If not, it must be moved. And then add an interlock. And only then can you properly/legally/safely use a generator with your panel.

#### Step 2 - Plug/Cord

There are 30A 4-wire 2 hot/neutral/ground plugs and cords. You may have one on your clothes dryer. But there are also 30A 120V **1** hot/neutral/ground plugs and cords, designed for small RV usage. A typical small (up to 10kW or so) generator will include:

- A duplex NEMA 5-15 or 5-20 for 15A (and possibly 20A) 120V loads.
- A NEMA TT-30 30A 120V - this is what you are trying to use
- A NEMA 14-30 30A 240V/120V - this is typical (my house is wired for this)
- A NEMA 14-50 50A 240V/120V - this is what you have on your house right now

Generally speaking, you want to use a 240V generator to provide power when the utility power is off. The problem is that if you use a 120V generator then not only are you not able to power any 240V loads (which is not usually such a big deal with a small generator since the 240V loads generally use more power than a small generator can supply) you also can only run 1/2 your panel unless you connect the two hots together.

So the *best* solution is to get a larger generator. But that costs, and may simply not be worth it for occasional use.

As far as connecting things together, you have two options. With either option, wire up a cord using appropriate components purchased from reliable sources, or find a *UL-listed* or *ETL-listed* cord.

Both types will have a TT-30 male (to go into the generator) and a 14-50 female (to go into the inlet at your house).

Both types will have neutral connected to both ends and ground connected to both ends.

The single hot will have the hot wire from the TT-30 connected to one of the hot wires on the 14-50. Depending on which pin is connected, one or half of your 120V loads will work and the other half will not. The "halves" are usually in rows going down the panel. Typical breaker numbering:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12
```

In this example, one hot gets 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10 and the other gets 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12. But double-stuff breakers will confuse this...

The other option is to connect *both* hots on the 14-50 to the single hot from the TT-30. That will make everything "live", but 240V loads will still not work. Technically that would be bad for multi-wire branch circuits (MWBC) but with such a small generator that is realistically not a concern.

An example I found at Home Depot is this [AC Works RV Adapter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/AC-WORKS-RV-Adapter-TT-30P-RV-30-Amp-Male-Plug-to-RV-50-Amp-14-50R-Connector-RVTT1450/303873790) which *should* do the job well. I do not see any indication about UL or ETL listing, but it is sold by Home Depot, not a drop-ship from Amazon, so it should be legit.

#### 3 - Safe Generator Usage

A gas (gasoline, natural gas, propane) generator **must** (a) be at least several feet away from the house when in use - don't run it inside a garage or even a carport, (b) not have any windows or doors open in a straight path between the generator and the house - and that includes not running the extension cord through an open window or door. Carbon monoxide is a very real danger, and it kills without much warning because you can't smell it. (You can smell the gasoline burning, but that's not actually what kills you.)

The simple solution to avoid running extension cords through windows and doors is a proper inlet installation on the outside of the house. That conveniently also eliminates the need for "suicide cords".